# Python flask and restless - how to return gz file of json object

Tags: python, flask

I I am using flask-restless.  I am trying to respond of a get request of a gz file of a json object from s3 and do not understand how to send a gz file.

```
class report_download(Resource):

    def get(self,report_name):

        conn = boto.connect_s3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
        bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucketname)
        key = Key(bucket, report_name)
        key.get_contents_to_filename('/tmp/%s' % report_name)
        os.system('gzip /tmp/%s' % report_name)
        data = open('/tmp/%s.gz' % report_name).readlines()[0]
        return data


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 710, in finish
    self.wfile.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 279, in close
    self.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent-1.0b2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/gevent/socket.py", line 468, in sendall
    data_sent += self.send(_get_memory(data, data_sent), flags)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent-1.0b2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/gevent/socket.py", line 439, in send
    return sock.send(data, flags)
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe





127.0.0.1 - - [26/May/2016 03:29:03] "GET /api/driver/report/download/7000_upload_.json HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_RESTful-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 271, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_RESTful-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 268, in error_router
    return self.handle_error(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_RESTful-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 271, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_RESTful-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 268, in error_router
    return self.handle_error(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_RESTful-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 481, in wrapper
    return self.make_response(data, code, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_RESTful-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 510, in make_response
    resp = self.representations[mediatype](data, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Flask_RESTful-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/flask_restful/representations/json.py", line 20, in output_json
    dumped = dumps(data, **settings) + "\n"
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 250, in dumps
    sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 201, in encode
    return encode_basestring_ascii(o)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zipped data is binary, so, `readlines` probably only reads corrupted data.

You can use python module `gzip`, without the need of any external program:

```
import gzip

class report_download(Resource):

    def get(self,report_name):
        conn = boto.connect_s3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
        bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucketname)
        key = Key(bucket, report_name)
        contents = key.get_contents_as_string()
        data = StringIO.StringIO()
        zip = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=data, mode='wb')
        zip.write(contents)
        zip.close()
        return Response(data.getvalue(), mimetype='application/x-gzip')
```

Comment: Thanks. I have posted on the error that I get when i run your code.  I get unicode error

Comment: this seemed to work send_file(io.BytesIO(data.getvalue())

Comment: you probably want to give the correct mimetype. See my edit.